# Why is this flow activating an infinite loop?

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, power-automate-custom-connector

I don't know why this flow on power automate is activating an infinite loop.
I got the issues when i'm adding or deleting attachments, but i'm using just one ID

**Flow**

[image]

**Warnings**

[image]

I tried with trigger conditions, another flow options...

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a warning so it can be ignored but you need to make sure you action the advice given.

I can’t see it but I suspect your trigger is for items on a list that are also being updated as a part of your flow.

The flow is smart enough to know that you’re potentially developing an infinite loop but not smart enough to know if you’ve put enough safeguards in place to avoid it, i.e. by using triggers or conditions within the flow.

So bottom line, just make sure you’ve covered off and avoided the prospect of creating an infinite loop by updating something that is going to trigger this flow again.